# Number of Simultaneous Overlapping datetime(s)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-range, vba

I have two columns of date/time(s) and need to find out the maximum number of them that overlap at a particular time.

Use case is this: These are start and end times for phone calls and am looking to find the number of simultaneous calls.

```
Column A            Column B                 
8/06/15 00:17:00    8/06/15 00:19:00     
8/09/15 00:20:00    8/09/15 00:30:00     
8/09/15 00:25:00    8/09/15 00:40:00    
8/09/15 00:35:00    8/09/15 00:50:00     
8/09/15 00:45:00    8/09/15 00:55:00     
8/09/15 00:46:00    8/09/15 00:52:00
```

Expected Result:

```
Column A            Column B             Max Simultaneous    
8/06/15 00:17:00    8/06/15 00:19:00     0
8/09/15 00:20:00    8/09/15 00:30:00     1
8/09/15 00:25:00    8/09/15 00:40:00     1
8/09/15 00:35:00    8/09/15 00:50:00     2
8/09/15 00:45:00    8/09/15 00:55:00     2
8/09/15 00:46:00    8/09/15 00:52:00     2
```

The formula I am trying is this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$35006<=B2)*(B$2:B$35006>=A2))
```

Problem with this, is that it counts the total number that overlap, even if at any one point they do not overlap themselves - greatly increasing the desired result.

I asked the question poorly before:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32486571/

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit further? I don't understand your desired result in comparison to your use case.

Comment: It's helpful to think of it by the use case.  I have a list of phone calls, and I am trying to determine how many phone lines I need.  Calls start and end at various times, and when they overlap, I need another line.

Comment: Let me get this straight: Theres a phone call from 1 to 3, then theres another one from 2 to 4 (so theres one overlap). next one would be from 2.5 to 5 (3 overlaps). next one 6 to 7 (no more overlap). If so, the second row in your expected results is wrong.

Comment: Please explain further. The Max Simultaneous counts do not seem consistent, even with the use case.

Comment: The second row  [00:20:00 to 00:30:00]   intersects with the third row from 00:25:00 to 00:30:00 leaving 1 overlap.    The third row [00:25:00 to 00:40:00] intersects with the second row until 00:30:00 and then again with the fourth row starting at 00:35:00, but since the second row does not intersect with the fourth row, there is only 1 overlap at a time for the third row.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly you don't want to know not how many calls intersect each line, but at any given second how many calls are in progress.  Then find your max during a certain time range so you can know how many line you need for each given time frame, say hour to hour or minute to minute.  Is this correct?

Comment: yes.  that is correct.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6hnsaRAjasBWkN1R2FlN1d2ek0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The only way I can come up with through a formula is to create a column with every minute of that given day and then use countifs() to count how many calls are happening at each given minute of the day.  Then you can use that information to get your answers.

Comment: I thought I had it with a formula but I think I reached a dead end. Would it be OK to have a UDF solution?

Comment: I'd be happy with any solution that could get me the answer!

Comment: How large a span of time will you run a report for? Your sample data shows a time span of about three days.

Comment: I will be doing about a month at a time.  Prefer the year, but a good sample month will get me what I want.  In this case, there were 35006 individual records for the sample month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a Sub instead of a UDF. You can set the range of the phone call log in the square brackets on the second line of the routine. I've only tested it with your six rows of sample data. It will calculate the max lines and write them one column to the right of the log (column C in the example).

```
Public Sub MaxLines()
    Dim c&, i&, j&, k&, min_#, max_#, n&, v, w&(), vOut, r As Range
    Set r = [a2:b7]
    v = r
    With Application
        min_ = .Min(.Index(r, 0, 1))
        max_ = .Max(.Index(r, 0, 2))
    End With
    n = (max_ - min_) * 1440
    ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(v), 1 To 1)
    ReDim w(1 To n + 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        k = (v(i, 1) - min_) * 1440 + 1
        c = CLng((v(i, 2) - v(i, 1)) * 1440)
        For j = 0 To c
            w(j + k) = w(j + k) + 1
        Next
    Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        k = (v(i, 1) - min_) * 1440 + 1
        c = CLng((v(i, 2) - v(i, 1)) * 1440)
        max_ = 0
        For j = 0 To c
            If w(j + k) > max_ Then max_ = w(j + k)
        Next
        vOut(i, 1) = max_ - 1
    Next
    r.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 2) = vOut
End Sub
```